# Polynomial regression rules

Tags: regression, least-squares, polynomial

With OLS regression the errors must be normally distributed and be homoscedastic. Does these rules apply to polynomial regression as well?

Comment: Nothing changes when you add polynomial terms.  OLS can't distinguish between x^2 and some other variable that takes on the same values as x, squared.

Answer (score 3):

Polynomial regression is actually a particular case of linear regression.

Polynomial regression is nevertheless linear in the parameters (and, for that matter, linear in the columns of the $X$-matrix).

(Also see the first line of the [Wikipedia page on polynomial regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression).)

As a result all of the assumptions of linear regression still apply in this particular case of it.